# Xamarin ios app weird issue: just started crashing at start when running debugger, but not just running debug version

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

My app is fairly large, and is now being used successfully by 100s of users.  I started many years ago, and I am stuck at XF 4.8. I use the "SHARED CODE" paradigm. I have many pages derived from a class BasePage which is derived from ContentPage.  I have .xaml and .xaml.cs files nicely nested.  I have a lot of logging to both the Console and a file.

I just did a major merge of some code that diverged. One of the pages is called "InfPumpPage".  Like most of my pages, I do a new on it at startup.

HERE'S THE WEIRD: I log when I call do the new(), and I log in the first line of the constructor (before InitializeComponents).  When it crashes, I don't see the log msg in the ctor.  I say "when it crashes" because if I remove essentially all the code, it "works".  (Note, I did not change the XAML code.) But still weird -- there's a delay between the new() and the ctor log msg that does not exist for other pages.  Even with no code, it's about 1/2 sec, compared to 4 msec worst case on the others, some of which are more complex.

EVEN MORE WEIRD -- when I start adding code back in, it still works, to a point, but it seems like every bit I add makes that delay longer.  When it gets to about 12 seconds, the debugger just reports "App Terminated".  Running the app not under the debugger it runs nicely -- new to ctor log msg 1 msec.

WEIRDEST YET -- in desperation, I deleted the .xaml & .xaml.cs file, and re-created with Add Item. I hacked on it to get publics satisfied for the rest of the code.  Essentially no XAML.  IT STILL HAS THE DELAY, and I suspect if I add enough code I can get it crashing again.  BUT -- no evidence that ANY OF THE CODE HAS BEEN RUNNING!

I've changed linker behavior for Debug from Don't Link to Link Framework.  I've tried with and without "Enable the Mono Interpretter" checked.  I've also radically changed the order the pages are constructed in -- does not affect.  I've wondered if there was a Garbage collection, but now the object is tiny compared to others (change in total memory 13K vs 1.4MB for the more complex one).  Just updated Win VS 17.3.6 today, no change. Latest Xamarin.iOS (16.0.0.75).

UPDATE: Unbelievably, after learning this hard lesson, I've been having this again. This time I changed from "Link Framework" to "Link All", which seemed to fix for the better part of a day. But then it started misbehaving again.  I updated my Mac OS and my XCode version, and it's working again.  Now if I can only remember to delete .vs trick next time.
This question was tagged as closed because it needed more detail, but I don't know how I could add more than this.

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  You've posted multiple paragraphs of descriptive information but there is not really any useful details - code, errors, exceptions - that we could use to help you.

Comment: Delete bin and obj folders? More effective than "clean solution". If testing on emulator, Tools / Android Device Manager / rt-click emulator, "Start with Factory Defaults". This clears low-level emulated device state.

Comment: *"Like most of my pages, I do a new on it at startup."* FIRST display a simple page. THEN start doing "new" on other pages, *in a background thread*. This should be safe, if none of those pages are being displayed yet in UI. OTOH, in your Release version, with appropriate settings, "new" time should not be significant - it is "layout / measure / inflate / draw" time that becomes slow in Xamarin Forms. You might be doing work in constructor that would be better done as a separate task, in background thread, before page is needed. Accessing data, etc.

Comment: @Jason, well, that's part of the thing ... no explanation, just "app terminated".  The code is big, and reducing makes the issue go away, so narative seemed right.

Comment: do you have any exception or crash logging tools enabled?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Yeah, forgot to mention that I've been regularly doing the bin/obj dance, as someone has called it. No difference.  Oh, and I've been using real devices:  iPad Air 4th gen mostly today, iPad 8th gen, and sometimes my iPhone 8.

Comment: @Jason, I disable them in debug, so I debugger point a big ugly finger at it.

Comment: I have a thought, and I think it might pan out -- I deleted the .vs directory (and bin/obj) and rebuilt.  The delay is gone.  I'm going to put back the real code and see if I'm up again.  But, wife rang dinner bell.  We used to call this a "priority interrupt". Thankful for all the interest so far!

Comment: If the app just terminates when you're trying to debug, then maybe it's iOS that is actively shutting it down because it takes too long to load. There is a 7(?) second threshold on iOS to start an app, if it takes longer, the operating system will terminate the app. I'm writing this, because you say that it works when you run the debug version without debugging. Could be related to Hot Reload, which sometimes takes very long to initialize

Comment: Your build output window must have an exception stack trace

Comment: @ewerspej, yeah I think that it is iOS shutting it down.  There was NO exception shown on the Output window. It is like it's too long processing code.  I shut off all Hot Reload, which I would love to use, but it seems like it wasn't working for me anyway, and it seemed like a major suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is still WEIRD, but I'm past it.  Deleting the .vs (hidden) directory (and, bin/obj) and rebuilding fixes everything.

This is starting to really be like VisualStudio was told to do something special with the file or class called InfPumpPage.  I don't know what this would be, I sure didn't do it on purpose, and I looked everywhere I could think of to undo it.  I'm REALLY CURIOUS if someone has a clue.